# Retornar valor do banco para textbox Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Como retorno um valor de uma coluna do banco `sql` para um `textbox` em `asp.net mvc` ?
Criei o textbox, criei uma propriedade dentro de uma classe.

```
<label>
       @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IRPJ) : 
       @Html.TextBox("txtIRPJ", Model.IRPJ , new {@class = "form-control form-control-custom", style="width:60px"})
</label>
```

Como faço isso ?

Tenho uma classe alem do model onde estou fazendo assim:

```
 public BoletoModel IRPJ(string Tipo)
        {
            StringBuilder qryIRPS = new StringBuilder();
            qryIRPS.Append("Select Descricao1 ");
            qryIRPS.Append("from TiposNfsApp where ");
            qryIRPS.Append(" Tipo = '" + Tipo + "'");
            DadosNfsApp objDados = new DadosNfsApp();
            BoletoModel bm = new BoletoModel();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = objDados.RetornarDataSet(qryIRPS.ToString()).Tables[0];

            bm.IRPJ = dt.Rows[0]["Descricao1"].ToString().Trim();
            return bm;
        }
```

Comment: Primeiro descreva em que *Model* este valor está. No ASP.NET MVC não se acessa apenas uma coluna de um registro, mas o registro todo de uma vez.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, to tomando um pau desse mvc pqp. rs vou colocar como fiz até agora na pergunta.

Comment: Você está usando Entity Framework? Está bem fora do padrão isto que você está fazendo.

Comment: Não. Cara nem eu sei o que estou fazendo kkk. To completamente perdido nisso. Que saudade de webforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você usando errado sua *View*. Altere para o seguinte:

```
@model MeuProjeto.Models.BoletoModel // Preencha o nome da classe com o namespace. Aqui chutei um só pra você pegar a ideia.

<label>
       @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IRPJ) : 
       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => modelIRPJ, new {@class = "form-control form-control-custom", style="width:60px"})
</label>
```

Comment: beleza, arrumei aqui. Mas e o processo de retornar do banco o valor que eu preciso de uma coluna passando um parametro, como posso fazer ?

Comment: Isto não faz parte da pergunta. Faça outra.